# Rsyslog not writing any logs from Cisco network devices - all other remote syslog works fine

Tags: linux, logging, cisco, rsyslog, syslog

tcpdump confirms valid syslog is coming in from multiple remote systems - servers and Cisco network equipment.

OS is Linux RHEL 8.8

The servers all come in fine and write to disk, and are shown as being local1:info, but none of the Cisco devices will write to disk. Cisco all shows as being local7:info in tcpdump.

I'm thinking there is a kernel filter or something that is telling Rsyslog to discard/ignore the local7 stuff, but I don't know how to verify that.

I've run this but found nothing suspicious:
grep -r 'local7' /etc/

How can I troubleshoot this further and find out what is happening to these Cisco logs?
I've never seen this before.

The Rsyslog configs are fine, they are just set for `*.*` to go to /var/log/remote/00514/%fromhost-ip%/syslog.log and that works for everything so far but Cisco.

The IPs or hostnames for Cisco do not show up in the Rsyslog debug log either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom Rsyslog Configuration for Cisco Devices:

Create a custom Rsyslog configuration file for Cisco devices, e.g., /etc/rsyslog.d/cisco.conf.

In this file, specify the facility and severity levels for Cisco logs and define where they should be written. For example:

`# Log all local7 messages from Cisco devices to a specific file local7.* /var/log/cisco.log`

Restart rsyslog after making changes
`systemctl restart rsyslog`

And check selinux
To check if SELinux is blocking your syslog logs, you can use the `audit2allow` tool, which is part of the `policycoreutils-python` package. Here's how to check SELinux audit logs and generate the necessary SELinux policy rules:

1. Install the `policycoreutils-python` package if it's not already installed:

   ```bash
   sudo yum install policycoreutils-python  # For RHEL/CentOS
   # OR
   sudo dnf install policycoreutils-python  # For Fedora
   ```
2. Check the SELinux audit logs to see if there are any denials related to your syslog logs. You can use the `ausearch` command:

   ```bash
   sudo ausearch -m avc -ts recent  # Replace "recent" with a specific timestamp if needed
   ```

   This command will display AVC (Access Vector Cache) denials. Look for entries related to your syslog or Rsyslog process.
3. Once you've identified AVC denials related to Rsyslog, you can generate SELinux policy rules using `audit2allow`. For example, if you see denials related to Rsyslog trying to write to a specific directory, you can create a custom SELinux module to allow those operations:

   ```bash
   sudo ausearch -m avc -ts recent | audit2allow -M my-rsyslog-policy
   ```

   This command will generate two files: `my-rsyslog-policy.pp` and `my-rsyslog-policy.te`. The `.pp` file is the compiled policy module, and the `.te` file is the human-readable policy source.
4. Install the custom SELinux policy module:

   ```bash
   sudo semodule -i my-rsyslog-policy.pp
   ```
5. Restart the Rsyslog service to apply the new SELinux policy rules:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl restart rsyslog
   ```
6. Monitor the SELinux audit logs to ensure that the previously identified AVC denials no longer appear.

By following these steps, you can identify and resolve SELinux denials that may be blocking Rsyslog from functioning correctly. Be cautious when creating custom SELinux policy rules, as they should only allow necessary operations and maintain the security of your system.

Comment: Wow thanks. I wouldn't be surprised if it's SELINUX.
But why would I need a separate Cisco config, I have *.* going to /var/log/remote/00514/%fromhost-ip%/syslog.log

I'm just trying to understand why I'd need the local7.* when that should be covered.

I'll try the SELINUX stuff, probably take a few days to get changes approved.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. We disabled SELINUX with setenforce 0 and the logs still don't come in.